# A mysterious way for solving ODE of type $P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$ where $P$ and $Q$ are homogenous function of degree $n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Definition:

We say $f(x,y)$ is homogenous of degree $n$ if for each $\lambda$, $f(\lambda x, \lambda y)=\lambda^n f(x,y)$

We call a differential equation of form $P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$ homogenous, If $P$ and $Q$ are two homogenous functions of degree $n$.

---

I've read in a book that **all** of the homogenous ODE's can be solved by these substitutions:

$y=vx$ , $dy=vdx+xdv$

Mysteriously, That seems to be working!

I have two questions regarding this way of solving homogenous ODE's.

$1$) How did they come up with this solution? They could do many other substitutions. Why this one?

$2$) Why can we assume that there exists something like $v$ that $y=vx$? Maybe there is not a linear relation between $x$ and $y$! How are we sure?

Note: I want to understand this method. That's the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\nu$ is not a constant, i.e. $y=\nu x$ is not a *linear* relation, but a change of variables $(x,y)\mapsto(x,\nu)$
$$
\begin{cases}
x=x,\\
\nu=\frac{y}{x}
\end{cases}
$$
Since $P$ and $Q$ are homogeneous one can factor out e.g. $x$ to get
$$
x^nP\left(1,\frac{y}{x}\right)dx+x^nQ\left(1,\frac{y}{x}\right)dy=0.
$$
Then one can cancel $x^n$ and it is obviously worth to try $\frac{y}{x}$ as a new variable $\nu$. The diferential of the product is $dy=d(\nu x)=\nu dx+x d\nu$ and we get 
$$
[P(1,\nu)+\nu Q(1,\nu)]dx=-xQ(1,\nu)d\nu\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad 
\frac{dx}{x}=-\frac{Q(1,\nu)}{P(1,\nu)+\nu Q(1,\nu)}d\nu.
$$
Hence, we can separate the variables, which makes the equation easier to integrate, in general.

Comment: What was that part $P(1,v)$ or $Q(1,v)$? Why $1$ ?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade We have $x=x\cdot 1$ and $y=x\cdot \frac{y}{x}$. Then apply $f(\lambda a, \lambda b)=\lambda^n f(a,b)$ where $\lambda=x$, $a=1$, $b=y/x$.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was awesome